# How can I submit an HTML form without the use of HTML helper function

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-form, laravel-helper

Just using the HTML form, how can I submit a form to a store function in the resource controller, if the route is */register*. Please help, I've tried inserting 'post' method in the form tag,it's not working. Meanwhile the name of the store route is customer.store. I just don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Set up a route to handle the `POST` request that you are sending via `/register` to the appropriate controller and function... What have you tried so far? Do you have any code that we can help you debug?

Comment: The it's a resource route pointing to a resource controller. I just wanna be able to submit my form to the store function in the controller

Answer (score 1):

Like James said, simply create a post-route, to which your form-submit points. Then set this route to your store-function in your controller. If you have the `route::auth()` in your routes, put this to the end. This one catches normally catches your `/register` route.

Your form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
    <!-- Don't forget your csrf -->
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <!-- Rest of your form -->
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

Your `routes.php`

```
// GET
Route::get('/register', function(){
    return view('register-form');
});
//or
Route::get('/show-form', 'FormController@showForm');

//POST
Route::post('/submitted-form', 'FormController@register');

//GET and POST combined
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/form-handler', 'FormController@formHandler');
//And finally
route::auth();
```

But maybe you could hook in the `AuthController`. This controller normally handles the registrations (take a look at the `register`method in combination with the `create`method).

Comment: @HammedDapoAjibade:  So please mark the question as answered ;)